# Here i am trying to fill the studentList which is an array.For now i have showed for 2 students only but getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting the below warning and unable to print the array.
    /* warning: format %d expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' */
o/p: [4196160][4196160] ??

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
# define MAX 3
typedef struct{
    int rollno;
    int credits;
}list;
typedef struct{
    int  no_of_students;
    list studentList[MAX];
}recordList;
void setList(list *l, int rollno, int credits, int *msgLen)
{
    l->rollno = rollno;
    l->credits = credits;
    *msgLen = sizeof(rollno) + sizeof(credits) + sizeof(list);
}
int main()
{
    recordList *r;
    list l;
    r = malloc(sizeof(recordList));
    r->no_of_students = 2;
    int index = 0;
    int msgLen = 0;
    setList(&r->studentList[index], 1, 5, &msgLen);
    setList(&r->studentList[index++], 2, 6, &msgLen);   //trying to fill the data for index = 1
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
      printf("[%d]", "[%d]", r->studentList[i].rollno, r->studentList[i].credits);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `r->no_of_students = 2;` Where does `r` point to? Which address did you assign to it?

Comment: ` recordList *r` You have a pointer for `recordlist` but the memory for the structure is not allocated. You need to do a `malloc` or use the variable directly `recordlist r` `r.no_of_students=2` etc

Comment: how to do the same by function call ? 
eg:
int main()
....
func(r->studentList[index] , 1);
}

public void func( how should i declare the parameters here)

Comment: regarding: `printf("[%d]", "[%d]", r->studentList[i].rollno, r->studentList[i].credits);`  This contains a syntax error.  It shows a single output format specifier, followed by 3 parameters.  Suggest: `printf("[%d], [%d]", r->studentList[i].rollno, r->studentList[i].credits);`

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not any memory allocated to r. Use malloc to allocate memory:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
recordList *r = malloc(sizeof(recordList));
```

Comment: ohh yes.Thank you

Comment: how to do the same by function call ? 
eg:
int main()
....
func(r->studentList[index] , 1);
}

public void func( list *l, int rollno)  // is this correct way to do by function call ???

Comment: Do you want allocate memory in func? or just want assign rollno?

Comment: inside the studentList array , say for every array index i want assign rollno

Comment: You can define func as: 
void set_rollno(list* l, int r_no)
{
  l->rollno = r_no;
}
  and call like this: set_rollno(&r->studentList[index], 1);

Comment: i have corrected and posted it, is there anything i m still missing as i couldn't see the o/p. @alborz

Comment: @MAMTHASRI
You have one unused variable, i mean the "list l;" line is redundant. And also edit the printf in this manner: "printf("[%d] , [%d]\n", r->studentList[i].rollno, r->studentList[i].credits);"

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results